# Qt QNetworkAccessManager get doesn't work for all websites

Tags: qt, get, qnetworkaccessmanager

any idea why this code works for some webpages and for some not?

```
QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply *reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.fi")));
QEventLoop eventLoop;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
eventLoop.exec();
qDebug(reply->readAll());
```

With www.google.fi it prints source code but eg. www.ampparit.com doesn't work. There's no redirects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and both work for me. But both cases cease to work when dropping the "http://". Is it possible that you are using it in one case but not the other?

Comment: I restarted Qt Creator and now both fail. qDebug() << reply->errorString() returns "Unknown error". I guess something is wrong with my computer since it works with you.